# Local Silverstripe instance site pointing to live site for assets

Tags: silverstripe

I have an instance of Silverstripe that we have copied off a webserver that we host. We are trying to get it running locally so we can modify it but when I run it locally all assets point to the live site. Also I cannot access the login, or Admin pages of the CMS.

When I try access any local pages it states "Server Error" in the page content

Is there a place in the code where I can change the paths to assets to local, and also access the Admin area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're running a local copy of the database, and don't have any exotic changes to the way `File` is handled SilverStripe should be resolving file paths using the `BASE_PATH` and `BASE_URL` constants.

For logging in you'll want to add to the bottom of `mysite/_config.php` locally something like:

```
    define('SS_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'dev');
    SSViewer::set_source_file_comments(true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    Security::setDefaultAdmin('admin', 'admin');
    // Email::setAdminEmail('admin@example.org');
    define('SS_LOG_FILE',dirname(__FILE__).'/'.basename(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'.log');
    ini_set('error_log', SS_LOG_FILE);

    Director::set_environment_type('dev');
```

This should give you enough debug information to solve most issues.

Comment: Thanks mate, just to confirm the _config.php file in question. Is this the one in the cms folder?

Comment: You'll want to add the snippet to the bottom of the mysite/_config.php file. I've clarified that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for that btw there is a double comma after SS_LOG_FILE. I tried to edit it myself but was not able to save my edit

Comment: Thanks mate I'm still getting errors but I can now access all the pages locally. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ (which also works for Silverstripe), to do a search and replace for all occurences of the old domain.

This would mainly work for images paths that are inside of content fields of course. Otherwise, SS should automatically convert the paths, as the accepted answer suggests.